# Why can't I find installed apps under guest account in Windows 8?

Tags: windows, windows-8

I installed some apps in Windows 8 as an administrator. I can find those apps in the Start menu and launch them with no problem, but when I switch to a guest account, those apps don't show up in the Start menu and I have no way to launch them. Their icons don't show up on the Desktop either. These apps are older and may not be compatible with Windows 8. I had a similar problem in Windows 7 with these same apps, but was able to get around by following the recommendations posted on this site.

Comment: Can you start them by going to `C:\Program Files\App-Vendor\App-Name`?  
Get the folder by logging in as Administrator, right-click at it and select `Properties`.